# Make Windows act as a hardware mouse through USB?

Tags: usb, mouse, device-driver

When I connect a unit (smartphone) to my computer with usb I want the unit to think that it has connected to a regular mouse (usb otg).

Is there any such driver for either Windows or Linux?

*(You probably wonder why, and even though it offtopic I can say that my android screen and touch is broken. I need to unlock the lockpattern by controlling a mouse while at the same time receiving screenshots from ADB.)*

Comment: Why not connect the phone directly to a mouse? Android supports that

Comment: As Timmy wrote: connect a mouse to your unit, and the unit thinks "it has connected to a regular mouse".

Comment: @Timmy Like I said my screen is not functioning, it is very hard to unlock with a dark screen.

Comment: @Aron It wasn't clear in the question that the screen is dark. I thought by broken you only meant the glass and touch interface, not the display. In this case, I suggest you reword your question to indicate that you are also searching for screen mirroring solutions and not just mouse support

Comment: @Timmy ok maybe it wasn't clear, but I did say I needed screenshots from ADB :) However I did actually solve my problem with a usb mouse. I realized you could connect to ADB wirelessly, thus leaving the micro-usb port free for a mouse while I at the same time could request feedback screenshots through ADB. If any is interested feel free to ask me, although it is offtopic.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that worked. I suggest you post it as an answer and mark it as accepted so the question wouldn't remain unanswered, and will remain as a reference for future visitors with similar problem